# Django - how to filter on a comma seperated string

Tags: django

At my Django models.py I have a "genre" field (models.TextField). This fields contains sometimes only one string and sometimes a comma separated list of string like this:

> Comedy, Action, Drama

Or

> Action, Fantasy

or as mentioned only one string e.g. only

> Comedy

Now at my view I want to do something like this:

```
queryset_comedy = Movies.objects.get_queryset().filter(genre__in=["Comedy", "Family"])
queryset_action = Movies.objects.get_queryset().filter(genre__in=["Action", "Adventure"])
queryset_drama = Movies.objects.get_queryset().filter(genre__in=["Drama", "Thriller"])
```

I mentioned that my Query only matches field values which are standalone according to the genre field. For example Movie element one has the following genre string:

Comedy, Action

and Movie element Two only has "Comedy" as standalone string. Than the query outputs only Movie objects which have the string "Comedy" standalone and not Comedy, Action.

How can I make a Movie element match when multiple sorting strings are given for genre?

Comment: Perhaps your genre should be it's own Model and then can use a manytomany relationship

Comment: I also thought about that but its currently quite complicated to implement. I possible I would like to stay with string matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an immediate solution, you could `OR` multiple `contains` queries together. I.e.

```py
queryset_comedy = Movies.objects.filter(Q(genre__contains="Comedy") | Q(genre__contains="Family"))
```

However, I would recommend migrating to a more suitable representation, for example

- Use [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) (PostgreSQL-specific)
- Store a list of strings in a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield)
- Store genres in another table and associate it with `Movies` using a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)

Comment: good hint. At least that works. I absolutely agree with your suggestion, that creating a proper relation is much cleaner. Thanks for your quick help